# Pinch and Zoom WIN2D

Tags: c#, canvas, xamarin.forms, uwp, win2d

I drawn some arcs and line in canvas using WIN2D.Now I am trying to use ManipulationDelta to implement pan and pinch but my image lost quality.   I think that the image don1t update, so this make it lost the quality in zoom. Here my code...

```
    private void Preview_Draw(Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasControl sender, Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasDrawEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            string GCodefile = ((ltvSelectExecution).SelectedItem as FolderFilesInfo).Name + ((ltvSelectExecution).SelectedItem as FolderFilesInfo).Extension;
            var EntityArcLines = execution.GetArcLinesParams(GCodefile, null, false);
            var pathGeometric = execution.GetPathGeometry(EntityArcLines);
            int flag;

            CanvasPathBuilder pathBuilder = new CanvasPathBuilder(ManipulateMe.Device);
            pathGeometric.ForEach(t =>
            {
                Vector2 finalPoints = new Vector2()
                {
                    X = (float)t.Xf,
                    Y = (float)t.Yf
                };
                float r = (float)Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(t.I, 2) + Math.Pow(t.J, 2));
                float x = 7;
                float y = 7;
                var clockwise = t.DirectionRotate;


                CanvasSweepDirection canvasSweepDirection = clockwise == 0 ? CanvasSweepDirection.CounterClockwise:CanvasSweepDirection.Clockwise;
                flag = t.G == 0 ? 0 : 1;
                if (t.I != 0 || t.J != 0)
                {
                    pathBuilder.BeginFigure((float)t.Xi, (float)t.Yi);
                    pathBuilder.AddArc(finalPoints, x, y, (float)0, canvasSweepDirection, CanvasArcSize.Small);
                    pathBuilder.EndFigure(CanvasFigureLoop.Open);
                }
                else
                {
                    pathBuilder.BeginFigure((float)t.Xi, (float)t.Yi);
                    pathBuilder.AddLine(finalPoints);
                    pathBuilder.EndFigure(CanvasFigureLoop.Open);

                }



            });
            CanvasGeometry triangleGeometry = CanvasGeometry.CreatePath(pathBuilder);

            using (var drawSession = args.DrawingSession)
            {


                drawSession.DrawGeometry(triangleGeometry, Colors.White, (float)1);

            }



        }
        catch(Exception ex) 
        { var teste = 0;
        };
    }
```

Can someone help implement pinch and zoom in this code?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by this word `but my image lost quality`?How it distorts? Could you please post some sreenshots or a  basic demo about it?

Comment: Jessie Zhang Thank you for your interest in helping me.
I actually solved my image quality issue, but now I have a new issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59286258/pinch-and-zoom-uwp-default-position-and-size

I am grateful if you can help me.